# If condition not matched in DOM XML parsing activity

Tags: java, xml, dom, domparser

I am a newbie in XML JAVA parsing using DOM and have built a small parser to read an application XML file with more or less standards structure. XML file extract is as follows:

```
 *<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<applications>
<application name="CustomerApplications/TEST3/">
    <service name="INFileAdapterConfiguration.aar">
        <deploymentStatus>Success</deploymentStatus>
        <serviceInstance name="TEST3">
            <machine>test</machine>
            <status>Unknown. HawkAgent on test is not responding</status>
        </serviceInstance>
    </service>
    <service name="OUTFileAdapterConfiguration.aar">
        <deploymentStatus>Success</deploymentStatus>
        <serviceInstance name="TEST3">
            <machine>test</machine>
            <status>Unknown. HawkAgent on test is not responding</status>
        </serviceInstance>
    </service>
</application> 
<application name="TEST2">
    <deploymentStatus>Undeployed</deploymentStatus>
</application>
 </applications>
```

My objective is to filter the results based on the value of a specific element called "deploymentStatus": if the element value is set to "Success", then I would still print the child nodes and attributes, but if it any other value than "Success" then I would just print out something like "Application undeployed" and not read the childs.

Currently I am able  to get all applications names, however in the final result I lose the other nodes and child values (deployment Status, ServiceInstance, machine, status). Parser code below:

```
*import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Hrb_auto {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {
        final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        final Document document= builder.parse(new File ("C:\\Temp\\hrb_check    \\AppStatus.xml"));    

        final Element racine = document.getDocumentElement();   


        final NodeList racineNoeuds = racine.getChildNodes();
        final int nbRacineNoeuds = racineNoeuds.getLength();

        for (int i = 0; i<nbRacineNoeuds; i++) {
            if(racineNoeuds.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                final Element application = (Element) racineNoeuds.item(i);

            System.out.println("\n Application name: " + application.getAttribute("name"));

            final NodeList AppNoeuds = application.getChildNodes();
            final int nbAppNoeuds = AppNoeuds.getLength();

            for (int j = 0; j<nbAppNoeuds; j++) {
                if (AppNoeuds.item(j).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    final Element service = (Element) AppNoeuds.item(j);
                    if (service.hasAttribute("name")) {       
                    System.out.print("\t Service name: " + service.getAttribute("name"));

                    final Element deploymentStatus = (Element) service.getElementsByTagName("deploymentStatus").item(0);
                   final Element serviceInstance = (Element) service.getElementsByTagName("serviceInstance").item(0);


                    if (deploymentStatus.getTextContent() == "Success") {
                    System.out.print("\t deploymentStatus: " + deploymentStatus.getTextContent());
                System.out.print("\t Service Instance: " + serviceInstance.getAttribute("name"));

                final Element machine = (Element) serviceInstance.getElementsByTagName("machine").item(0);
                final Element status = (Element) serviceInstance.getElementsByTagName("status").item(0);

              System.out.print("\t  machine: " + machine.getTextContent());
            System.out.println("\t status: " + status.getTextContent());     

                   } else {
                System.out.println("Service disabled, no service to be checked");
            }

                    }
                        else {
                        System.out.println("Application undeployed, no service to be checked");
                    }

            }

            }
                }


        }

    }

    catch (final ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (final SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

}
```

}

Result obtained:

```
 *Application name: CustomerApplications/TEST3/TEST
 Service name: INFileAdapterConfiguration.aarService disabled, no service to be   checked
 Service name: RTCISOutFileAdapterConfiguration.aarService disabled, no service to be checked*
```

Expected result:

```
*Application name: CustomerApplications/TEST3/TEST
 Service name: INFileAdapterConfiguration.aar    deploymentStatus: Success   Service Instance: TEST3      machine: test  status: Unknown. HawkAgent on test is not responding
 Service name: OutFileAdapterConfiguration.aar   deploymentStatus: Success   Service Instance: TEST3      machine: test  status: Unknown. HawkAgent on test is not responding*
```

Any help provided would be great!

Comment: Can you please provide an excerpt of your input xml. This would help a lot understanding your question.

Comment: Hello, I have added an extract of the input xml file to be read.

Comment: Sorry, can you recheck if you added the example? I don't see it.

Comment: Definitely...not my day today :). It had not been properly taken into account. Now it should be OK.

Comment: You are welcome. What I needed to know is that whether there is a default namespace (there is not) and how the path to the application and service elements look like.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote "Any help provided ...", I suggest using [a library](http://xmlbeam.org) I'm affliated with. Without having an XML example I could not figure out all details, but your solution could look like this:

```
    public class Hrb_auto {

    public interface Service {
        @XBRead("./@name")
        String getServiceName();

        @XBRead("./deploymentStatus")
        String getDeploymentStatus();

        @XBRead("./serviceInstance/@name")
        String getServiceInstance();

        @XBRead("./serviceInstance/machine")
        String getMachine();

        @XBRead("./serviceInstance/status")
        String getStatus();
    }

    public interface Application {
        @XBRead("./@name")
        String getName();

        @XBRead("./service")
        List<Service> getServices();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Application> applications = new XBProjector().io().file("<path to data>").evalXPath("/applications/application").asListOf(Application.class);
        if (applications.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No applications found");
            return;
        }
        for (Application app:applications) {
            System.out.println("Application name: "+app.getName());
            if (app.getServices().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Application undeployed, no service to be checked");
                return;
            }
            for (Service service:app.getServices()) {
                if ("Success".equals(service.getDeploymentStatus())) {
                    System.out.print("\t deploymentStatus: " + service.getDeploymentStatus());
                    System.out.print("\t Service Instance: " + service.getServiceInstance());
                    System.out.print("\t  machine: " + service.getMachine());
                    System.out.println("\t status: " + service.getStatus());
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println("Service disabled, no service to be checked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By creating two interfaces ´Service´ and ´Application´ you can use the projector to use them as object oriented views to your XML data. The mapping between XML and Java is done via [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

After refining the paths, this program prints out:

```
Application name: CustomerApplications/TEST3/
     deploymentStatus: Success   Service Instance: TEST3      machine: test  status: Unknown. HawkAgent on test is not responding
     deploymentStatus: Success   Service Instance: TEST3      machine: test  status: Unknown. HawkAgent on test is not responding
Application name: TEST2
Application undeployed, no service to be checked
```

Comment: Hello, I have added an extract of the input xml file to be read

Comment: I added the path to the application elements and in the application the path to the services. This should work now.

Comment: I tested and fixed the path to the machine and state elements.

Answer (score 0):

That's a typical example of incorrect use of `==` for string comparison:

```
if (deploymentStatus.getTextContent() == "Success") {
    ...
}
```

Use `equals` instead, and your code should work as expected.